# Threads read/writing at the same time

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I don't care whether `Thread1` changes `Flag1` at the same time `Thread2` changes `Flag1`, is there anything else to worry about besides logic errors? Will it cause a crash etc if:

1. `Thread1` and `Thread2` read `Flag1` at the exact same time?
2. `Thread1` is writing to `Flag1` at the same time as `Thread2` is reading `Flag1`?

In these examples, `Flag1` is a `bool`.

Comment: You might want to think carefully about what "the exact same time" really means and how these operation occur on a digital device.

Comment: Neither will acsue a crash by itself unless the flag is a property of an objecttyat might not be instanced. But you could miss changes in state, or detect the same one in both threads. So what would happen would depend on what the change in state does. Making it thread safe is much easier than trying to cope with the fallout of it being unsafe

Comment: "_besides logic errors_" since you don't care about program logic, why do you even bother? A simpler program is "hello world". It may not do what you wanted to do, but when you don't care about logic errors...

Comment: It's worth reminding that though you can't read and write a `bool` variable at the same time, you can write and read a "data structure" at the same time, like reading `vector[0]` and writing to `vector[1]` is ok. The key is *you can't read and write to a **atomic** data type at the same time.*

Comment: hi @ Rick ATOMIC data types are the "scalars" that store one value at a time (int, float, boolean, etc)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the rules of the C++11 memory model:

1. *Thread1 and Thread2 read Flag1 at the exact same time?* This is always safe.
2. *Thread1 is writing to Flag1 at the same times as Thread2 is reading flag1?* This is a data race.

A data race is undefined behaviour. Although it's unlikely to crash on any sane hardware, it's undefined behaviour, so anything could happen.

Comment: C++03 doesn't mention threading so there's no guarantee of **anything** working at all.  C++11 offers guarantees whih are agreed on by compiler and hardware vendors, and mostly represent a formalisation of existing practice.  Do you have a better source for what's guaranteed and what isn't?  I don't, so can only answer in terms of the C++11 memory model.

Comment: @EitanT: The question is tagged "c++ multithreading".  There is no concept of "thread" in C++03, so by inference this must be C++11, and Jonathan's answer is the only correct one so far.  If the questioner wants to know about some platform-specific threading model, he needs to identify the platform.

Comment: Come on, the tags should not be interpreted word by word. They are merely topic identifiers, as the question regards threads and C++ in general, and not necessary a specific standard.

Comment: So do you have a better reference for the semantics of data races in C++?

Comment: @JonathanWakely You must agree that in case the OP is using C++03, referring to the C++11 standard would be irrelevant, no? In any case, the answer heavily depends on the OS, the platform and the hardware. In most cases a crash would not occur at all. That's all anyone can say, I guess.

Comment: @EitanT, no, it's not irrelevant, because the C++11 memory model is in many ways a formal definition of existing practice. Do you know any compilers which plan to implement a different memory model now or in the future?  If not, then surely advising people to follow those rules is sensible.

Comment: @Jonathan I'm not saying the answer is wrong, I'm just saying that the part where you're saying it's C++11 might be a little off. But again, details, details...

Comment: Besides, the "concurrent reads are ok, writes must be serialized" memory model is far older than C++11, see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/thread_safety.html for a similar set of rules for STL containers and POSIX uses similar rules

Comment: Where did I say it's C++11?  I never said that, I only said what C++11 says about the question.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Does this also imply that that writing, and only writing, to a shared variable is also safe? Assuming that **no** read will be performed during the lifetime of the threads?

Comment: @SvinSimpe if any one thread writes to a shared variable, no other thread can read **or** write it concurrently. Only concurrent reads are OK.

Comment: hi @Jonathan Wakely "Thread1 is writing to Flag1 at the same times as Thread2 is reading flag1? This is a data race" - regularly your answer applies to any programming language (it is the OWN nature of THREADS, regardless of the language always), doesn't it? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, 2 threads cannot access the same memory in the exact same time.

Even on parallel computing, these assumptions would be handled automatically by the processor.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_Random_Access_Machine

So the answer is no crash.
You will have logic errors of course but since you don't care :p.

Comment: "_2 threads cannot access the same memory in the same time."_ And what about shared memory?

Comment: Same time meaning in clock time. They actually take turns to access memory.

Comment: I see what you mean now, but I'd say that your phrasing is somewhat misleading.

Comment: I would say that in the simplest model (that I believe the OP is referring to), two threads may be said to run concurrently but technically they don't. And therefore simultaneous physical access to the same address is impossible.

Comment: However, if the read/write operation is not complete before the threads switch action, there might be a case where the OS/hardware might lock the resource (and potentially raise an error to the other accessing thread). Generally speaking that would be automatically handled by the CPU/driver/OS, but for that to answer correctly, we'll have to know more details about OS, the platform and the type of hardware.

Answer (score -1):

The flag should be marked as `volatile`. This will ensure your compiler does not optimize read/writes in a way that is inconsistant.

I believe read/writes to bool are atomic - so I don't think you will have any other issues if you don't care about the order of access.

Comment: No, `volatile` has nothing to do with threading, and no, accesses to bool are not guaranteed to be atomic in general (some hardware might give stronger guarantees, but that's not portable.) Although volatile will prevent the compiler re-ordering reads and writes it does nothing to prevent the hardware re-ordering them.  Use atomic types or atomic operations to get the correct semantics.

Comment: @JonathanWakely umm.. I'm sorry I don't understand - why do you say volatile has nothing to do with threading?

Comment: @JonathanWakely - he doesn't care about re-ordering

Comment: So why suggest volatile?  It has nothing to do with threading, see http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/c++mm/user-faq.html

Comment: @JonathanWakely I specifically mentioned that volatile is to prevent the compiler from making optimizations. Its a `best effort` suggestion. We don't want the compiler to optimize out the whole condition on the flag, do we? Clearly, he doesn't care about the order - so no-need to use atomic.

Comment: Agree with Chip in concept, the author needs to make sure that memory is read/written to (load with acquire/store with release) by Thread 1 and 2, but volatile turns off all optimization on the variable, so it could be a bit too much. Just use the acquire/release semantics and you'll be fine.